# Cannot use custom dataset in official resnet model, raised tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.CancelledError

Tags: python, tensorflow

These days I modified the official `cifar10_main.py` , in order to train the kaggle dogs_cats_redux dataset.

First, I created the tfrecord files, following the standard pipeline, you guys can download the tfrecord files [here.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1P7zGwxIY0ynFAN5PrmK71IMu51m4U2Rt)

And then, I wrote some tfrecord parsing functions and dogs_cats_model class, and the rest of the code remain the same as the original resnet repo, you guys can check my `main.py` [here](https://gist.github.com/JustinhoCHN/d6d4534d322595dc562ff0d0d59b8a59).

But when I run the `main.py`, it raised the CancelledError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 326, in <module>
    main(argv=sys.argv)
  File "main.py", line 321, in main
    shape=[_HEIGHT, _WIDTH, _NUM_CHANNELS])
  File "/home/jto/projects/dogs_cats_tf/official/resnet/resnet_run_loop.py", line 396, in resnet_main
    max_steps=flags.max_train_steps)
  File "/home/jto/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 363, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/home/jto/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 843, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/home/jto/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 859, in _train_model_default
    saving_listeners)
  File "/home/jto/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1059, in _train_with_estimator_spec
    _, loss = mon_sess.run([estimator_spec.train_op, estimator_spec.loss])
  File "/home/jto/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 567, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/home/jto/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1043, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/home/jto/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1134, in run
    raise six.reraise(*original_exc_info)
  File "/home/jto/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/jto/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1119, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jto/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1191, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/home/jto/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 971, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jto/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 900, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/jto/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1135, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/jto/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1316, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "/home/jto/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1335, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.CancelledError: Queue '_2_input_producer' is already closed.
         [[Node: input_producer/input_producer_Close = QueueCloseV2[cancel_pending_enqueues=false](input_producer)]]
         [[Node: IteratorGetNext = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[?,224,224,3], [?,2]], output_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Iterator)]]
         [[Node: IteratorGetNext/_2401 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_534_IteratorGetNext", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
```

I've googled so many solutions, most of them say that's because somehow the data queue is stopped, or we didn't start the queue correctly, solutions like:

```
# Start the data queue
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess, coord)
```

But the official resnet_run_loop.resnet_main() using tf.estimator.Estimator to train the model, the source code doesn't need to start the queue like that, so how can we solve this problem? Any ideas would be appreciate.

system info:
ubuntu 16.04 LTS
tensorflow-gpu v1.8.0
cuda 9.0
cudnn 7.1

The github issue is [here.](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/4724)